# Copy and share text into Clipboard from listview

Tags: android, xml, parsing, copy, clipboard

I am developing a basic Android App which parses an xml file from assets using SAXParser, and I have successfully parsed the xml.

I then register the parsed text for Context using the following code:

..........

```
this.registerForContextMenu(content);


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copy");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");

    if (selectedText.size() > 0) {
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copy");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Copy") {
        copySelectedText(getSelectedText());
        return true;
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Share") {
        shareSelectedText(getSelectedText());
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public boolean copySelectedText(String text) {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newIntent(position, getIntent());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    return true;
}

private void shareSelectedText(String text) {
    copySelectedText(null);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Shared from MyApp");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
            "Sharing text using"));
}

public String getSelectedText() {

    //How do I code here?? }

    return null;
}
```

Using the above code, Context menu works just fine when I long click on any portions of the parsed text. But my problem here is, I don't know to put the parsed text into clipboard. Could somebody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Here is how I did it.

I had parsed an xml file from assets folder and passed the result in an array of listview. My initial problem was how to copy the text on longclicking the texts. But now I somehow managed to solve my problem, and I am sharing it here. Hope it helps someone with a similar problem.

```
@Override public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_COPY, 0, "Copy");
menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXTMENU_SHARE, 1, "Share");
}


@Override public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {

case CONTEXTMENU_COPY:
AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

//The textview which holds the parsed xml
CharSequence selectedTexts = ((TextView)menuInfo.targetView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Intent", (CharSequence) selectedTexts);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected text is copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

case CONTEXTMENU_SHARE:
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
CharSequence textToShare = ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Hiaite zangin share in"));
}
return super.onContextItemSelected(item); }
```

All I needed to do was this line of code, after identifying which item is longclicked!!

```
CharSequence textToShare = ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
```

It's so simple I could have kicked myself. I hope it is of help to some struggling newbies like myself and save somebody a whole lot of beginner's headache! :P